# Comparing various date/time types

Tags: sql, database, ansi-sql, database-agnostic

Is it defined how a date should be compared to a timestamp with a timezone or a timestamp without a timezone? For example, something like:

```
SELECT
    DATE '2014-01-01' = TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-01-01',
    DATE '2014-01-01' = TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2014-01-01',
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2014-01-01' = TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2014-01-01'
```

I've seen various implementations, some that error and some that allow it. For example Postgres allows all three, whereas BigQuery only allows comparing a date to a timestamp without a timezone.

My thinking is that a date doesn't necessarily imply that the time with that day is `00:00:00` -- for example, if the tv air date of an episode is July 1, 2023, it doesn't necessarily mean that the air date is at midnight UTC. So I think in the strictest sense, equality doesn't make sense across various date/time types (as it might across various numeric types).

Comment: If it's defined anywhere I guess it would be in an ISO standard

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid does SQLServer support comparing various different date/time types without explicitly casting?

Comment: Yes. But it always implicitly casts them to match behind the scenes. This shows which data types can be implicitly casted and which will throw an error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16 . I'm not sure which wau it casts them though.

Comment: Your TIMESTAMP literals are all invalid. And you can't compare dates with timestamps. (According to ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Unfortunately, most databases implement different date and time data types, different arithmetic, and also have strange quirks with them (MySQL is notorious for this). You won't find "database agnostic" logic for them.

Comment: @jarlh which part is invalid? Here is the query running in Postgres -- https://gyazo.com/edef80d2cacd25adbdf4cf2bdbd342c4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023(E)

5.3 < literal >

```
<timestamp literal> ::=
  TIMESTAMP <timestamp string>

<timestamp string> ::=
  <quote> <unquoted timestamp string> <quote>

<unquoted timestamp string> ::=
  <unquoted date string> <space> <unquoted time string>

<unquoted date string> ::=
  <date value>

<unquoted time string> ::=
  <time value> [ <time zone interval> ]

<time zone interval> ::=
  <sign> <hours value> <colon> <minutes value>
```

Which means a TIMESTAMP literal can look like

```
TIMESTAMP'2023-06-21 08:03:33'
TIMESTAMP'2023-06-21 08:03:33.123'
TIMESTAMP'2023-06-21 08:03:33+10:00'
```

4.6 Datetimes and intervals

*Items of type datetime are comparable only if they have the same < primary datetime field >s.*

I.e. a TIMESTAMP and a DATE are not comparable, because they do not have the same primary datetime fields.

```
<primary datetime field> ::=
  <non-second primary datetime field>
  | SECOND

<non-second primary datetime field> ::=
  YEAR
| MONTH
| DAY
| HOUR
| MINUTE
```

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. So is the way postgres does it totally nonstandard? Maybe that's confusing the data type with the literal value: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006081

Comment: does the comparison definition allow comparing a `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` then? I.e., two timestamps, one with a timezone and one without?

Comment: Yes, you can compare two timestamps, one with a timezone and one without.